# Multiple auth-method in web.xml

Tags: tomcat, spnego

I have configured Kerberos authentication in tomcat using Built-in Tomcat support.
Below is the part of web.xml, currently only domain users are able to authenticate & access application for non domain users (external pc's) the site is not able to access and givning below response.

> HTTP Status 401 \u2013 Unauthorized

Type Status Report

Description The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

Is there a way we can redirect to username & password prompt for non domain pc's
i have added below lines in  web.xml

```xml
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>APP1</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
     <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
   <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat developer here...the code you are using has been donated by me many years ago.

No this is not possible, `web.xml` allows exactly one authentication scheme. Your best bet is to modify the authenticator, add Basic support and perform a `kinit` within Java, obtain ticket, extract information from security context. Same approach is done by mod_auth_gssapi.